# Loading Google Visualization before JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I was having problems with the DOM since elemnets inside of google visualization tables/graphs were loaded before jQuery.
Therefore, i realized that i need to load google visualization before jQuery .ready()..

Loading Google visualization is done by:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["linechart","table","piechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGraph);
```

How can I make sure Google visualizaion is loaded BEFORE running the .ready() function?

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `document.ready` inside a function and it'll fire when called if it's already ready, like this:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["linechart","table","piechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(myLoad);

function myLoad() {
  drawGraph();
  $(document).ready(function() {
   //Stuff here
  });
}
```

It should be noted here though, you might not need document.ready at all, you could just stick the contents in this same function.

Alternatively, you could stick the `drawGraph();` call as the first thing in your `.ready()`.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.
As for the alternative solution, isn't there a risk that if I call drawGraph() from within my .ready() , the google packages could not be loaded yet from google?